# What's the correct syntax for multiple ValidationError functions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I have a model on which I want to raise 2 conditional validation errors:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.personal_id_type == 0 and self.personal_id is None:
        raise ValidationError(
            {
                'personal_id_type': [
                    "ID type can not be 'None' if you have set a value.",
                ]
            }
        )

    if self.personal_phone_mobile is None and self.personal_phone_direct is None:
        raise ValidationError(
            {
                'personal_phone_mobile': [
                    'Please enter at least one personal phone number',
                ],
                'personal_phone_direct': [
                    'Please enter at least one personal phone number',
                ],
            }
        )
```

This displays the errors in isolation fine, so the logic is sound, however when both errors exist only the first exception is raised. Have I got the syntax wrong?

I want to be able to continue to use this in a `Model` (not a `Form`) display the error messages against the `field_names`.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the documentation in the [*raising multiple errors* section [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#raising-multiple-errors).

> If you detect multiple errors during a cleaning method and wish to signal all of them to the form submitter, it is possible to **pass a list of errors to the `ValidationError` constructor.**

They include an example:

> ```
> # Good
> raise ValidationError([
>     ValidationError(_('Error 1'), code='error1'),
>     ValidationError(_('Error 2'), code='error2'),
> ])
> ```

You thus can implement such validation with:

```
def clean(self):
    data = super().clean()
    errors = []
    if condition1:
        errors.append(ValidationError('Error1', code='error1')
    if condition2:
        errors.append(ValidationError('Error2', code='error2'))
    # ⋮
    if conditionn:
        errors.append(ValidationError('Errorn', code='errorn'))
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)
    return data
```

Note that for ***field-specific* cleaning**, you should implement a `clean_fieldname` method. See the [*cleaning a specific field attribute* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, apologies I forgot to mention I was raising the validation on a `model`; does this approach apply to both `models` and `forms`? The docs do not mention much about `model` validation.

Comment: @alias51: the two are indeed quite similar: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: Thanks, where I have errors displayed next to the `field_name` in the question example, how would I include this in your answer?

Comment: @alias51: as said, for field-specific cleaning, you implement `clean_fieldname` methods, and thus raise validation errors related to that specific field.

Comment: This is conditional logic on the values of multiple fields, so I don't think field specific cleaning would work would it?

Comment: @alias51: it will, you can fetch `self.cleaned_data` for a dictionary that maps field names to cleaned values. This is the result of calling `clean` on the *field* objects (so not the `clean_fieldname`s).

Comment: It doesn't appear you can use self.cleaned_data on a model (at least for me it does not return any errors as `self.cleaned_data` is `Null`). Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: @alias51: no, that is only for `Form`s that's correct. For models, it is just `self.field`.

Comment: Thanks. Could I just build a dictionary  `error_dict = {}` and then add to this before `if error_dict: raise ValidationError(error_dict)`, or would you recommend against this?